# MS SQL to PostgreSQL Sync and Migration

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, migration

I need to migrate data from MS SQL to Supabase (PostgreSQL), I will need to keep
data realtime synced between MS SQL and Supabase until I can shutdown the legacy system.

Providers like Hevo seems to have services to help with that https://hevodata.com/learn/mssql-to-postgres/#hevo ...

Would that be the simplest solution or is there out there any opensource tool that can help with it?

Comment: https://debezium.io/

Answer (score 1):

I found this opensource tool to make the sync between SQL Server and Postgres.  I haven't use yet, but maybe it works for you. SymmetricDS.
https://www.symmetricds.org